# Does anyone has any example using dotpulsar ith oauth2 client credentials?

Tags: c#, apache-pulsar

I'm trying to covert a java source code to c# but cant find the implementation of auth2 on DotPulsar , can someone help me out on this?

```
var auth = AuthenticationFactoryOAuth2.clientCredentials(issuer, credentials, audience);

var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(@"certificate.pfx"));
var client = PulsarClient.builder()
          .serviceUrl(new Uri("pulsar+ssl://test:6651"))
          .listenerName("external")
          .tlsTrustCertsFilePath(clientCertificate)
          .authentication(auth)
          .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this pull request

https://github.com/apache/pulsar-dotpulsar/issues/92

https://github.com/apache/pulsar-dotpulsar/issues/101

These indicate a workaround as the client doesn't have auth native yet.

You can also try this other DotNet client for pulsar

https://github.com/fsprojects/pulsar-client-dotnet

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, it's the fist time i'm trying to use this library and also the fist time i'm trying to connect to this specific pulsar server. I'm trying to use the Notnet client, using the Oauth2 Example and still no success :-( In the refered example the Oauth Autentication is created with 3 parameters (issuerUrl, audience, fileUri). the first 2 i think i have them correct but for the last one a Uri is required and i have a local Json file with 4 values, type, client_id, client_secret and issuer_url.

Comment: My question is , I've tried also in the last parameter (Fileuri) to send as file://myfile.json and none of it works. I allways get this error from the apache. info: PulsarLogger[0]
      Connecting to Broker (LogicalAddres Unspecified/apacheserver.cloud:6651, PhysicalAddress Unspecified/apacheserver.cloud:6651) with maxMessageSize: 5242880, brokerless: True
warn: PulsarLogger[0]
      GetPartitionedTopicMetadata failed will retry in 100 ms
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

Comment: Her's an example of the json that i have.....{
  "type" : "client_credentials",
  "client_id" : "ext-serverxxxx",
  "client_secret" : "alskdjOzogDFGG4e3Gxu3MKiqxP7D324",
  "issuer_url" : "https://serverxxxx/realms/testnetwork"
}

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the problem. Case someone has the same problems just try to add a slash to the server address
"serverxxxx/realms/testnetwork/"
instead of
"serverxxxx/realms/testnetwork"

Worked for me.